# CRITICAL: tensorflow:Category has no images - validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to retraining the Inception v3 model in tensorflow for my own custom categories. I have downloaded some data and formatted it into directories. When I run, the python script creates bottlenecks for the images, and then when it runs, on the first training step( step 0) it has a critical error, where it tries to modulo by 0.  It appears in the get_image_path function when computing the mod_index, which is index % len(category_list) so the category_list must be 0 right?

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

EDIT: Here's the exact code I'm seeing inside docker

```
2016-07-04 01:27:52.005912: Step 0: Train accuracy = 40.0%
2016-07-04 01:27:52.006025: Step 0: Cross entropy = 1.109777
CRITICAL:tensorflow:Category has no images - validation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 824, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 794, in main
    bottleneck_tensor))
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 484, in get_random_cached_bottlenecks
    bottleneck_tensor)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 392, in get_or_create_bottleneck
    bottleneck_dir, category)
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 281, in get_bottleneck_path
    category) + '.txt'
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 257, in get_image_path
    mod_index = index % len(category_list)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've modified retrain.py to ensure that at least there is an image in validation (line 201*)

```
if len(validation_images) == 0:
   validation_images.append(base_name)
elif percentage_hash < validation_percentage:
```

(*) Line number may change in future releases. Look at the comments.

Answer (score 21):

**Fix:**

The issue happens when you have less number of images in any of your sub folders.

I have faced same issue when total number of images under a particular category was less than 30, please try to increase the image count to resolve the issue.

**Reason:**

For each label (sub folder), tensorflow tries to create 3 categories of images (Train, Test and Validation) and places the images under it based on a probability value (calculated using hash of label name).

An image is placed in the category folder only if the probability value is less than the category (Train, Test or validation) size.

Now if number of images inside a label are less ( say 25) then validation size is calculated as 10 (default) and the probability value is usually greater than 10 and hence no image is placed in the validation set.

Later when all bottlenecks are created and tf is trying to calculate validation accuracy, it first throws an fatal log message:

> CRITICAL:tensorflow:Category has no images - validation.

and then continues to execute the code and crashes as it tries to divide by validation list size (which is 0).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't understand what you mean by "An image is placed if the probability value is less than the category (Train, Test or validation) size." though. As all the images are labelled, wouldn't TF just set aside a proportion of the images for training, testing, and validation?

Comment: Sorry, i meant, An image is placed in one of the Train, test or validation based on the probability value.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the above. BTW if the explanation satisfies the answer can you mark it has answer?

Comment: Actually, since the images are put into validation|testing|validating bucket based on a hash of their filename, it may occur that one bucket is empty. It just happened to me: 50 images per label, no image selected in for testing. The program doesn't check this: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/retrain.py#L190:L205. I created a dirty solution here, making sure that there will be at least one image in validating and testing sets: https://github.com/matthieudelaro/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/matthieu/scripts/retrain.py#L190:L211

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when running the retrain.py and when i set the --model_dir argument incorrectly and the inception directory got created in the flower_photos directory.

Please check if there are any directories in the flower_photos directory without any images.

Comment: I had this exact error, and this was the exact (correct) reason I had the error.

Comment: This answer is for similar issue with very similar error description but not for one from the question above. This is what I got and fixed it with @Praveen solution: `CRITICAL:tensorflow:Label inception has no images in the category validation.` So I put inception folder inside images folder, which was wrong. Anyway +1 for guiding me.

Answer (score 4):

1. This happens if you have too less images. Like Ashwin suggested, have at least 30 images.
2. Also the names of your folder is also important. Somehow your folder name can't have an underscore(_)

eg. **These names didn't work** : dettol_bottle, dettol_soap, dove_soap, lifebuoy_bottle

**These names worked** : dettolbottle, dettolsoap, dovesoap, lifebuoybottle

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error was caused by having folders in the training directory that did not have images in them. I was following the same "Poets" tutorial and ended up putting directories with subdirectories in the image dir. Once I removed those and placed only directories with images directly in them (no sub dirs) the error no longer occurred and I was able to successfully train my model.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to train using my own set of images (pictures of dogs instead of flowers), and ran into this same problem.

I identified that the problem for me ended up being that my folder names (category names) weren't present in the imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt file that gets loaded in the inception data that we are modifying.

By changing the name of my image folder from bichon to poodle, this started working, since poodle is in the inception map and bichon is not.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a "-" in my folder names. The moment I corrected it, the error vanished.

Comment: For me it was because the folder names started with an uppercase. Once it worked though, so that's really strange.

Answer (score 1):

As Ashwin Patti has answered, there is a possibility that the split directory for validation has no images due to a lack of images in the original label directory.

This explanation is supported by the warning when you try to retrain with labels that have less than 20 images:

> WARNING: Folder has less than 20 images, which may cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

This error went away for me after adding >50 images to each category

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add my own experience:

**Don't have spaces**
For me, it worked when all a folder name contained was a to z characters, no spaces, no symbols, no nothin'.

E.g `I'm a folder' is wrong. However, 'imAFolder' would work.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthieu said in comments, the solution proposed:

```
# make sure none of the list is empty, otherwise it will raise an error
# when validating / testing
if validation_percentage > 0 and not validation_images:
    validation_images.append(training_images.pop())
if testing_percentage > 0 and not testing_images:
    testing_images.append(training_images.pop())
```

wotks for me.

I'm wondering what the message "CRITICAL:tensorflow:Category has no images - validation" really means. Is it related to the error that was fixed or It could mean loss of accuracy? I mean, if was used few images, the results would not be as expected?

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact same problem. My folders were named correctly however my files were named name_1.jpg, name_2.jpg. Removing the underscore fixed the issue.